# req.body is [Object: null prototype] {} and req.files is empty when using multer to handle POST request containing form data

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-functions, multer

I'm trying to send form data using Postman to an express server hosted on Firebase functions.
This is the code I'm using to receive the POST request:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express = require('express');
import multer = require('multer');
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
const upload = multer().array("attachment");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/upload', upload, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

export const server = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here's the postman setup
[image]

When I send the post request the req.body and req.files are logged as the following:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "server"
>  [Object: null prototype] {}
>  []
i  functions: Finished "server" in ~1s
```

I feel like it should be dead simple... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

As requested here is the request header

```
{
    'postman-token': '816a8871-bb12-470f-93f8-13cb6024815d',
    host: 'localhost:5001',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------115218701862318827186009',
    'content-length': '316657',
    connection: 'close'
}
```

and here is the curl code

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5001/hosting-name/us-central1/server/upload' --form 'testKey="testValue"' --form 'attachment=@ <path_to_your_file>"'
```

Comment: show all sent request headers

Comment: also, please include your sample request in curl format, I don't have access to Postman and I'm having a hard time replicating your request.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this blog post: https://mikesukmanowsky.com/firebase-file-and-image-uploads/

Firebase and Multer DO NOT work together. I adapted the code in the blog post to work in my Typescript project here:

index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express = require('express');
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import formMiddlware from "./formMiddleware";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/upload', formMiddlware, (req: any, res: any) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);

    res.sendStatus(200);


});

export const server = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

formMiddleware.ts

```
import * as Busboy from "busboy";
import os from "os";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

type Dict = {
    [key: string]: any
}

function formMiddlware (req: any , res: any, next: any) {
    // See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data
    const busboy = new Busboy.default({
      headers: req.headers,
      limits: {
        // Cloud functions impose this restriction anyway
        fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
      }
    });
  
    const fields: Dict = {};
    const files: any[] = [];
    const fileWrites: any[] = [];
    // Note: os.tmpdir() points to an in-memory file system on GCF
    // Thus, any files in it must fit in the instance's memory.
    const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
  
    busboy.on('field', (key: string, value: any) => {
      // You could do additional deserialization logic here, values will just be
      // strings
      fields[key] = value;
    });
  
    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
      console.log(`Handling file upload field ${fieldname}: ${filename} (${filepath})`);
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
      file.pipe(writeStream);
  
      fileWrites.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        file.on('end', () => writeStream.end());
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {
          fs.readFile(filepath, (err, buffer) => {
            const size = Buffer.byteLength(buffer);
            console.log(`${filename} is ${size} bytes`);
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            }
  
            files.push({
              fieldname,
              originalname: filename,
              encoding,
              mimetype,
              buffer,
              size,
            });
  
            try {
              fs.unlinkSync(filepath);
            } catch (error) {
              return reject(error);
            }
  
            resolve();
          });
        });
        writeStream.on('error', reject);
      }));
    });
  
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
      Promise.all(fileWrites)
        .then(() => {
          req.body = fields;
          req.files = files;
          next();
        })
        .catch(next);
    });
  
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
export default formMiddlware;
```